# Not getting the expected speedup using OpenMP on non-trivial calculations

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I'm trying to learn OpenMP to parallelize a part of my code and I'm trying to figure out why it's not faster when using 2 threads instead of 1. Here's a minimal working example of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

class My_class
{
    public :

        // Constructor
        My_class(int nuIterations) 
            : prVar_(0),
              nuIters_(nuIterations)
        {} // Empty

        // Do something expensive involving the class' private vars
        void do_calculations()
        {
            for (int i=0;i<nuIters_;++i){
                prVar_=prVar_+i+2*i+3*i+4*i-5*i-4*i;
            }
        }

        // Retrieve result
        double getResult()
        {
            return prVar_;
        }

    private:

        double prVar_;
        int nuIters_;

};

int main()
{
    // Initialize one object for every thread
    My_class *test_object1, *test_object2;
    test_object1 = new My_class(1000000000);
    test_object2 = new My_class(500000000);

    // Set number of threads (use one line at a time)
    omp_set_num_threads(1); // One thread executes in 11.5 real seconds
    //omp_set_num_threads(2); // Two threads execute in 13.2 real seconds
    double start = omp_get_wtime(); // Start timer
#pragma omp parallel sections // Do calculations in parallel
    {
#pragma omp section
        {
            test_object1->do_calculations();
        }
#pragma omp section
        {
            test_object2->do_calculations();
        }
    }// End of parallel sections
    // Print results
    double end = omp_get_wtime();
    cout<<"Res 1 : "<<test_object1->getResult()<<endl;
    cout<<"Res 2 : "<<test_object2->getResult()<<endl;
    cout<<"Time  : "<<end-start<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running this using `g++ myomp.cpp -O0 -std=c++11 -fopenmp` gives the following execution time for 1 and 2 threads:

1. 1 thread : 11.5 seconds
2. 2 threads: 13.2 seconds

Is there some way I can speed this up for 2 threads? 
I am running this on a 4-core Intel i7-4600U and Ubuntu.

EDIT: Changed most of the post such that it follows the guidlines.

Comment: You have to give us more information in form of an [mcve] plus your hardware specifications, otherwise an answer is just guessing. Guesses include: Writing to shared cache lines, being memory bound, implicit synchronization, usage of shared resources that you are not aware of or combinations thereof.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'll try to work out an appropriate example and edit the post!

Comment: Done, hope it makes sense now!

Comment: If it's any consolation, it takes 8.9s on my iMac with 1 thread and 5.6s with 2 threads. I used `-O3` to compile.

Comment: I turned off optimizations on purpose to avoid affecting the result, my actual code is compiled using O3 but it's difficult to reproduce.. :(

Comment: Pro Tip: Don't benchmark with optimizations disabled unless you actually run your code in production with optimizations disabled. Unless you're trying to measure the impact of compiler optimizations itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two effects here:

1. Cache line contention: You have two very small objects that are allocated in dynamic memory. If they end up in the same cache line (usually 64 byte), the threads that want to update `prVar_` will both compete for the level 1 cache, because they need exclusive (write) access. You should have observed this randomly: sometimes it is significantly faster / slower depending on the memory location. Try to print the pointer addresses and divide them by 64. To address this issue, you need to [pad / align the memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20792203/620382).
2. You have a huge load imbalance. One task is simply computing twice as much work, so even under idealized conditions, you will only achieve a speedup of 1.5.

Comment: I added a 1,000 element array of doubles to the private variables (to try and separate the two objects further than one cache line) and it made no difference at all...

Comment: What does "no difference" mean? If you already get the 1.5x speedup, then you are likely not affected by 1) in the first place.

Comment: Agreed. I was trying to say that there doesn't seem to be any cache line contention, but I phrased it badly. I also tried making the two workloads identically sized and the speedup was indeed 2-fold. So, on my machine at least, it appears to be almost exclusively your second effect. Have my vote :-)